# Need to assign textbox value to ui list after ajax success

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

I have different lists in my form

```
    <c:forEach items="${cmlist}" var="records"> 
        <ol class="dd-list"  id="chapterlist" >
        <li id="cs" class="dd-item" data-id="1" value="${records.levelID}">
            <div class="dd-handle">
           <a href="#subchaptercontent">Chapter:  ${records.levelName} </a>
    <img class="hand-cursor" alt="" src="../resources/images/edit.png" 
       title="edit" id="edit_record_btn" style="float:right;margin-top:-20px;" 
            data-toggle="modal" data-target="#windowTitleDialog" 
               onclick="javascript:editChapter(${records.levelID})">
            </div></li>
        </ol>
    </c:forEach>
```

I have ajax function for storing list values to database after storing I need to print this value in list but i cant need loading the browser just assign the value to list from text box.
how to do that
here my ajax function:

```
var sampName = document.getElementById("sampName").value;

    $.ajax({
        type : "post",
        url : "editSamplee?clg="+clg,
        data: JSON.stringify(courseStructureData),
        dataType:'json',
        contentType:'application/json',
        mimetype:'application/json',
        cache : false,
        beforeSend : function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            },
        success : function(response) {
            console.log("Success: ");
            //window.location = "coursecontentmain?clg="+clg;
            $("#windowTitleDialog").hide();
            $(".modal-backdrop fade in").hide();
            $(".modal-body").hide();
            sampName=$("#chapterlist li a").parents('li').text() ;
            },
        error : function(xhr) {
            console.log("Sorry, there was a problem! " + xhr.status);
            },
        complete : function() {
            console.log("Request complete");
            }
    });
```

Could you please help anyone

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified what are the content of list to be saved and what is the json element you are getting from the server but highlevel idea is like this -

in success function of the ajax call you are getting response as json so you can use it to cunstruct li element like this -

```
success : function(response) {
    $('#chapterlist').append('<li id="'+response.id+'" value="'+response.value+'"></li>');
}
```